# Who is responsible for /usr/share/dict/words ? (slurs found)

Tags: files, filesystems, words

I am writing an application that makes use of /usr/share/dict/words file to generate session keys.

I was appalled to find that the most egregious of ethnic slurs - the 'N-word' (in different spellings) in the file.

Who is responsible for the maintenance of this file, and why are these words in the file?

Comment: those words are racial slurs, not ethnic

Answer (score 7):

In most, if not all, Linux distributions, the file comes from [Spell Checker Oriented Word Lists](http://wordlist.aspell.net/).

The words in the file are there for the same reason they are present in a dictionary: they are part of the language. The particular words you mention are [identified as offensive](https://github.com/en-wl/wordlist/blob/f6b071244ce65b0a95ae052043042e85eed72815/scowl/misc/offensive.1).

Comment: Interesting paradox that identifying offensive words requires the creation of files devoted to them.